# Show specific content only on the domain home page to unsigned users

Tags: php, session-state, request-uri

I need to display the login form located in the external php file common for all pages of the site only on the homepage which may look like [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), [www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/) or [www.domain.com/index.php](http://www.domain.com/index.php), to unsigned visitors only.

I've made the following code to put before the braces:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["session"])
and
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/index.php'
or
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/')
```

but while it obeys URI rules and hides the form on secondary pages it still shows the login form to signed in visitors on the home page.

And I'm sure there should be other glitches.

What have I missed?

Comment: Is there a flag in the session you use to indicate if someone if a guest or logged in? If so, just check for that flag before rendering the form, regardless of the page you're on. Ex. `if ($_SESSION['guest]) { ... renderForm(); }`

Comment: I think you must put OR condition in a brackets. So, if must be `if(!isset($_SESSION["session"]) and ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/index.php' or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/'))`

Comment: @NurMuhammad it looks like I have skipped the brackets, indeed. That happens when one is very far from coding but tries to do something useful during several hours. ) If there are no more underwater stones in my (and your's - thanks for the brackets tip) solution please make an answer so I could upvote it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must put OR condition in a brackets.

So, it must be:

```php
if (
  !isset($_SESSION["session"]) and 
  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/index.php' or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/')
) {
  // Your code
}
```